# Ball passing through box collider

Tags: unity, collision-detection

My ball which has a circle collider 2D component occasionally passes through my box collider2D object. Both objects have rigidbodies attached. I have set a high mass for my box collider and a small mass for my ball. Strangely enough, it doesnt pass through every time (maybe due to varying velocity). Basically i am making pong.

[image: Ball details]

[image: Box details]

Comment: Did you try to increase the thickness of the paddles?

Comment: Just tried it and its working now. I cant believe i didn't try that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ball -at high velovity- will be before the box in one frame and behind the box in the next: so no collision has occured.

To fix this make sure the collision is continious or interpolated.

Set your collision mode to DynamicContinious for high velocity objects or Continious for fast objects. This does have a bit of an impact on performance if you have a lot of objects so just apply it to objects that move fast.

See: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CollisionDetectionMode.html

Answer (score -1):

It turns out all i had to do was increase the thickness of the box collider.

Comment: While this works for your situation now, there is a solution for this problem ("bullet-through-paper" as it is usually called) so you won't need to change your objects- you could have thin paddles if you like. See my answer for the details.